# HTML form submit multiple values

Tags: php, forms

I need to have the submitted fruit names to be printed after "Sadrzaj korpe:", i.e "apple, orange, banana".

My code only prints one fruit.

```
<form>  
    <label for="voce">Voce:</label>
    <input type="text" name="voce">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ubaci voce u korpu"><br>

 </form>  
    <?php
 if ($_GET["submit"]){
        if ($_GET["voce"]){ 
                echo "Sadrzaj korpe je ".$_GET['voce'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to store somewhere those values(like in database) and later print them all on submit.

Comment: you wrote `if -> get submit -> get voce -> print out value of voce `... there is no hinting of saving you value in a db or array. if you want it to be saved, use then an array to save it in.

Comment: Do you want to submit multiple fruits in one GET request?

Comment: @dukaPA You have a couple of options, do you want a fixed number of fruit that can be submitted, or a dynamic number?

Comment: dynamic @AndrewBreksa

Comment: @dukaPA
This post will tell you how to handle an array of POST data on the backend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819920/best-way-to-handle-dynamic-amount-of-form-fields-in-php

This will show you how to make dynamic forms with jQuery: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the backend  (From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819920/best-way-to-handle-dynamic-amount-of-form-fields-in-php)):

`input type="text" name="hoursWorked[]" />` will internally convert to an array under        `$_POST['hoursWorked']`.

That means you can do something like this with the form:

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Then, in PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["mytext"])){       
    $capture_field_vals ="";
    foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
        $capture_field_vals .= $text_field .", "; //Here is where the values are concated to $capture_field_vals
    }
    echo $capture_field_vals;
}
?>
```

Regarding the dynamic form (From [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery)):

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

The HTML form itself:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check for $_GET, $_POST etc values.

Secondly, if I understand you correctly, you want to submit several fruit one after another and display them all in real-time?

For that you should use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Otherwise, if your goal is only to dynamically display data added on the client then use client side with a library like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or any other ones that use two-way data binding.

You don't need server side if just showing data changed data set to a user? You can send data to server when user has finished adding his list of fruits.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        echo "Yes";     
  }else{  
       echo "N0";
  }
```

Comment: This appears to be the answer to a completely different question